# Why can't I access this method defined in my model from inside my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I have this method in my videos controller:

```
def notifications
  erase_notification_count
end
```

It calls the `erase_notification_count` method defined in my user model:

```
def erase_notification_count
  new_notification_count += (self.notifications.count * (-1))
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
NameError in VideosController#notifications

undefined local variable or method `erase_notification_count' for #<VideosController:0x102f0fed0>
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the `erase_notification_count` on the User model, this means you must call it on a User object. You're trying to call it directly on the VideosController object.

Comment: yes. you will. If it's in a model you have to call it directly on an instance of that model. The controller is a separate class and has no magical ties to instances of a different class. It sounds like you need a much deeper understanding of OOP and MVC principles. Maybe go back to the basics a bit?